# Programatically Generating Entire Layout + Get Handle for Buttons + Get the Text In Text Field + Store button clicked and text entered in this layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have been stuck with a huge problem. I have an entire layout generated programatically based on JSON response. So the json response has mostly three main types

1) type: select ( A Yes/No Question)
2) type: textfield (A Edit Text with a textview above) 
3) type: file (image view)

So below is my custom EditText class: Note that I can get a handle using a getter there

```
public class CEditText extends LinearLayout {

    String title;
    EditText et;

    public CEditText(Context context,String title, String number) {
        super(context);
        this.title=title;
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(15, 10, 15, 10);
        setLayoutParams(lp);


        TextView t = new TextView(context);
        t.setText(number + "  "+title);
        t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        addView(t);


        et = new EditText(context);
        final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lparams.setMargins(25, 0, 0, 0);
        et.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        addView(et);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public EditText getEditText()
    {
        return et;
    }}
```

So based on parsing I add them to my layout like this:

```
  if(ques_type.equals("textarea"))
                {
                    CEditText et = new CEditText(this, 
                    ll.addView(et)
responses.add(new Response(ques_type, ques_name,et.getEditText().getText().toString()));
                    }
```

So this is totally dynamic. Based on the response of user, I have to store  it. If user enters text in edit text I have to store it, if user selects  a yes/no for 'select' question, I have to store that response. After storing the response **I have to pass all these  to a different activity, where the user review his feedback.** I approached this like this, but it was a big flop as data was not persistent:

- Create a response.java class, with question and response and id as its members.
- After getting a handle using my custom class, as soon as the user clicks or enters text on I use the handle to get response. Then I keep the response in a response object and add it to arraylist of response, which I soon realized was not correct ! Because if I get a handle to a created custom view and soon do a getText(), I wont be getting anything (as seen in above code). It should actually be in a button click event where user clicks it after he enters all the responses. So to get all these responses in a button click, I need to have a handle/reference  under the button click to all these dynamically generated views, whihc I cant figure out how. I badly need help with this and I would greatly appreciate if anybody could lend a helping hand. and i would be even lot more grateful if you could give me an idea about how can I pass the stored responses to other activity. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood something here, but can't you just store references to all these CEditText views in some List or array as you create them?

Then, when user clicks "submit" (or whatever you call it), you can iterate through all these views and get their values.

If you do not want to use List or array, you can always call getChildAt(int position) on the parent of all your CEditText views.

The easiest (and also probably ugliest way) to pass it to next activity would be to simply put all those user generated strings into array and send them via intent.puExtra().

But another suggestion is: Do you really need separate activity to enable user to review the data he submitted? Is it really that much different? Can't you just reuse the layout you already have and just change some backgrounds etc.?

(If this is not what you meant, please add some more info about the project/purpose of all this, so we can discuss it :))

Comment: Worked it out....thanks man..thought it was pretty huge change on this concept...but I started out with this idea ...thanks a lot...!